# Why this promisified JWT.verify isn't working?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

So I'm trying to promisify jwt.verify manually but for some reason it is not passing the decoded_token to the resolve function.

**This is working fine...**
[image]

**This isn't..**
[image]

**PromisifiedJWTVerify..**
[image]
Can someone please mention the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: I actually liked the code images. Gives SO a nice touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use invoke `resolve()` like that on `jwt.verify(token, secret, resolve)`, when you just do `resolve` you aren't invoking it, you're referencing it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

edit: Screw my answer above I think it's supposed to be like this

```js
jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, data) => {
  if (err) return reject(err);
  return resolve(data);
});
```

this is because the first parameter passed in the callback is the error, which you don't want to put in the `resolve` but in the `reject` while the second parameter is the actual data which in case you actually do want in `resolve`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback

Comment: shouldn't it be invoked by jwt.verify? for example when I'm passing a callback in jwt.verify, I'm not invoking it.. but passing it as a reference.. Thanks for the doc..

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's working now.. so from what I understand... resolve can only take 1 argument? what if I want to pass both err and data to resolve?

Comment: ok ok I got the answer... promise only treats first argument as a resolution value.. to pass multiple values I've to pass them as a object or array... Thanks again :)

Answer (score -2):

The solution of your problem is this:

```js
const promisefyJWTToken = (token) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (token) return resolve(jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY));

    return reject('Invalid Token');
  });
};
```

Comment: Please review [answer] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1030169)